# Hide the dock in Mission Control and Launchpad?

Tags: macos, dock, mission-control, launchpad

I am really fed up with the Mac OS Dock showing in Mission Control and especially Launchpad.

Is there any way at all (even if I have to program it myself) to hide it in Mission Control and Launchpad because it gets in the way.

I still want it to show on the desktop and when I have applications open.

Can the dock be hidden only for Mission Control and Launchpad in macOS ?

Answer (score 1):

You could make it very small by pulling on the divider that is located to the right, usually just before the trash (a line) and it will turn in to double arrow when you click on it.

Comment: When the Mission Control or Launchpad screen is displayed, the Dock is shown even if hiding is turned on, and option-command-D doesn't hide the Dock.

Comment: ups :) mia culpta !

Answer (score 0):

No, the dock is designed to show ever-present, so this isn’t a feature in macOS 10.15 and lower.